# Upload large JPEG to WebGL texture without stalling the main thread

Tags: javascript, jpeg

I am downloading JPEG images from the server, and I want to load them to a GPU texture. How can I do this without stalling the main thread?

My code looks like this:

1. Use HTMLImageElement to download the JPEG
2. Use the decode() callback to ensure that as much JPEG decoding occurs in the background
3. Create a canvas, and draw the image into the canvas
4. Use getImageData() to extract the RGBA buffer from the canvas
5. Use glTexImage2D to upload the RGBA buffer (I'm using emscripten)

For large textures (in this case it's 5184 x 3456), the texture upload is relatively fast (eg 20ms), but getImageData() is very slow (eg 400ms).

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works on Chrome. Other browsers either lack OffscreenCanvas, or their OffscreenCanvas doesn't support a '2d' context (at least this was true on 2021-07-03).

You can use Web Workers to decode the JPEG and acquire the ImageData object, so that the only remaining work that occurs on the main thread, is the upload to the GPU, via glTexImage2D.

This is what the Web Worker code looks like:

```
onmessage = function (ev) {
    let data = ev.data;
    if (data.type == "downloadBitmap") {
        fetch(data.url)
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => createImageBitmap(blob))
            .then(bmp => {
                let canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(bmp.width, bmp.height);
                let cx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                cx.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
                let imgData = cx.getImageData(0, 0, bmp.width, bmp.height);
                postMessage({ type: "downloadBitmap", url: data.url, imgData: imgData });
            }, err => {
                postMessage({ type: "downloadBitmap", url: data.url, error: err });
            });
    }
}
```

If you're using emscripten, then unfortunately you need to copy the ImageData into the emscripten heap before calling glTexImage2D. But if you have the luxury of using the Javascript webgl interface, then you can upload the ImageData object without this additional copy.

One interesting point is that you can theoretically go straight from ImageBitmap to WebGL texture, but in my testing, this still causes a large pause on the main thread. So the process of drawing the ImageBitmap into the canvas, and then using getImageData() to extract the RGBA buffer is indeed necessary.